# Good textbooks on Non-Euclidean Geometry?

Tags: geometry

I'm currently taking a class called Foundations of Geometry. We started with the stereographic projection and carried onward through fractional linear transformations, and now we are working with the Poincaré Disk Model. We've been finding things like non-Euclidean lines, circles with their non-Euclidean centers and non-Euclidean distances, delving into hyperbolic trigonometry. We don't use a textbook though, the professor just wrote up his own notes, and while good, they're restricted to just our 10 quarter class, and we're just studying one of the non-Euclidean geometries. So I was wondering if anyone had suggestions on some books that may cover more of the hyperbolic geometry or perhaps some elliptic, or any others in general. Thanks! =D

Comment: This must be a duplicate, and the most common answer must be Marvin Greenberg's book.

Comment: Here are some:  http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=marvin

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, I never really went on here before I made an account last month, I'll learn to use the search function next time

Comment: The search was based on knowing the answer already, but the Related links to the right of the question are often useful.

Answer (score 1):

I study geometry with "Geometria" book by Prasolov,Tikhomirov. Maby you will find  it in English..

Also wery good book is "Geometry" by M. Berger.